# Tensorflow CIFAR10 Tutorial: Determining number of epochs in training process

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, deep-learning, classification

This is probably a very basic question. I' am new to deep learning and from what I gathered until now, one generally creates batches of data and once all the training data has been used (or "enough" of it), the process is repeated a couple of times (each iteration is called an epoch). However, when I look at the tutorial of CIFAR10:

[CIFAR10 Tensorflow tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_train.py)

There is no such thing as epochs. They are only mentioned here:
[cifar10.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py)

as `NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN` , `NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_EVAL` and `NUM_EPOCHS_PER_DECAY`.

Do they use this to implicitly define the epochs?

```
num_batches_per_epoch = NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN /FLAGS.batch_size
```

I also ask because I'm a bit confused about how i should set the `num_epochs`argument here (in my own model):

```
tf.train.string_input_producer(...,num_epochs=num_epochs,...)`
```

should I just set it to `NONE` or do I have to calculate the number of epochs first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things in your question:

1. Understanding: One epoch does not mean one iteration for most situations. One epoch means one pass of the full training set. `NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN` etc. are defined [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L34) as 50000. CIFAR-10 has 50000 examples for training. Then it will be easy to understand `num_batches_per_epoch`.
2. As for coding, in `tf.train.string_input_producer(...,num_epochs=num_epochs,...)`, you can check [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/string_input_producer) that explains `num_epochs`. For CIFAR-10, you don't specify `num_epochs` (because this `string_input_producer` does not read each example directly. The database is divided into 5 parts/files, each of which stores 10000 examples, and `string_input_producer` reads files).

Comment: The `max_steps` flag is set to 1000000 batches. And each batch has 128 examples. Is it correct to say that they have (1000000*128)/50000  = 2560 epochs?
So Basically I can set num_epochs to None and just stop everything at a certain number of steps

Comment: Yes, they have 2560 epochs. If you set `num_epochs` in `tf.train.string_input_producer(...,num_epochs=num_epochs,...)` to None, the reader will not stop reading data, until the step reaches `max_steps` when the whole program stops; if you specify the `num_epochs`, the reader reads only `num_epochs` times of its input and then it prompts an `OutOfRange` error.